# Can I use the command "$sudo ifconfig eth0" to set a static internal IP on a Lan? [Raspberry Pi OS]

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, static-ip, ifconfig

I am setting up a home server on a Raspberry Pi 4 with the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS on it. The first thing I want to do is create a static internal IP address for it so that I can reliably ssh into it from my laptop and not have to connect a monitor, mouse, and keyboard every time I want to do something on the server.

Most guides I've found have recommended doing things involving editing files, but occasionally I see people recommend using the following command:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.XXX
```

Is there any reason not to simply do this instead of editing a file? Does this change last "forever," so to speak, or just for the session? If my router re-boots, will that ethernet port still have the same internal IP address?

Comment: Well the effects of `ifconfig` (or better, `ip`) commands are "transient" / "volatile", meaning that you'll have to run them every boot (if you want the effects on every boot).